# Xpath contains() in Odoo 10

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-10

In Odoo 10, I'm trying to replace the content of this template by a xpath expression. What I want to do is just select the first  with "Weight" and replace it by "test"

```
<odoo>
<template id="report_delivery_document2" inherit_id="stock.report_delivery_document">
    <xpath expr="//th[@name='td_sched_date_h']" position="after">
        <th t-if="o.picking_type_id.code == 'outgoing' and o.carrier_id"><strong>Carrier</strong></th>
        <th t-if="o.weight"><strong>Weight</strong></th>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//td[@name='td_sched_date']" position="after">
        <td t-if="o.picking_type_id.code == 'outgoing' and o.carrier_id">
                <span t-field="o.carrier_id"/>
        </td>
        <td t-if="o.weight">
            <span t-field="o.weight"/>
            <span t-field="o.weight_uom_id"/>
        </td>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

In my module I've trying this code :

```
<odoo>
<template id="report_delivery_document3" inherit_id="stock_delivery_slip.report_sale_delivery_slip_createch">
    <!-- <xpath expr="//th[contains(., 'Weight')]" position="replace"> -->
    <!-- <xpath expr="//th/strong[text()='Weight']" position="replace"> -->
        <th>test</th>
    <!-- </xpath> -->
</template>
```

But nothing works,How can I select the "Weight" whithout adding attribute in "report_delivery_document2" ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply edit translation for that view (report_delivery_document2), and change :

```
<strong>Weight</strong>
```

into :

```
<strong>test</strong>
```

But if you want to keep xpath, just do this :

```
<xpath expr="//th[@t-if='o.weight']" position="replace">
```

Hope this will help.